Close login browser in .NET MAUI app after login process
I'm implementing login/sign up flow against Azure AD B2C using MSAL.NET in my .NET MAUI app.
This approach opens up a browser for the user to enter their credentials and I can see how this is definitely a more secure approach because I don't touch anything. Once the user logs in, my app takes over from there but the browser launched for the login process seems to stay "open".
I don't mean it's the active screen or blocking my app. It just seems to stay open and if the user goes through all active apps on their device, they'll see that browser with the login screen. I'm pretty sure this is the case with any mobile framework and not just .NET MAUI.
Is there a way to close that programmatically just to keep things nice and tidy?

There is no way can close the browser programmatically and different users may use different browsers. If you implement login/sign up in the webview of your app, you can close it.

Thank you for your response. I was under the impression that using WebView was frowned upon for user authentication process but I see that even in Microsoft documentation there are references to using WebView. So I switched to WebView and I think it's a much more user-friendly experience. Thanks!
